# Camunda REST - How to get flow expression possibilities

Tags: rest, bpmn, camunda

I'm still pretty new to Camunda.

I would like to illustrate a workflow which can be seen as more than a status flow. This flow should not contain any Java logic but should be controlled via the REST API.

Now I have a problem with the XOR gateway and REST-engine handling (see picture).

[image: Camunda BPM Example]

My goal is, if my process instance is waiting at the user task `Status 1`, that I get information how to proceed. So that if I want to reach the next state I have to specify if `test` is true or false.

I know that in the body of the [complete](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.7/reference/rest/task/post-complete/) REST-Call you can give variables and so the path is decided. What I want is that I know in advance which options are available (here: true and false) and can choose one of them.

So to my question: Is there a REST-Call that can tell me at the point `Status 1` that I can give either the variable `"test": {"value": "true"}` or the variable `"test": {"value": "false"}`?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No. In bpmn, you just know the current element, you cannot look ahead.  The options are part of your business logic, so you will have to provide the rest method yourself.

(long answer: using the java BPMN API and some fancy model analysis, this would be possible. But still not advised and error prone.)

Comment: But what is the common way to model the following correctly, for example: I am in status 1 and as a user I want to say that I want to move to the next status because status 1 is closed for me. Now I need for example a dropdown menu which offers me the possible options to choose from (here it would be just true and false, but it could also be "ok" or "not ok"). So there must be some way to query the options from within the code? If I now build this selection statically into the code then I have modeled the model in Camunda once and once in my code. I can't imagine that this is how it is done.

Comment: Well, that would be a case where you have to concurring state management systems in place. One explicit (the bpmn model), one implicit (assumption you make about allowed states that are not implemented in the process flow.  Using bpmn requires some shift in how to think business flow ... if the user task is to validate an order, the outcome might be "approved" and "declined".  Depending on which the user chose, your process will continue. But you can (and should not) look ahead in the process model and use that info in the task it self. .

Comment: Thats exactly what i want to do: validate a Document and outcome should be something like "approved" or "declined"... So i need to make a Selection for the user where he can choose between "approved" and "declined" and then i send this answer to the Model via REST? Isnt this redundant modeling? What if i change the flow conditional expression from `#{answer == "approved"}` to `#{answer == "true"}` ? Then I need to also change this in the selection for the user. I hope you understand what i mean.
With this Question it might be a little bit clearer:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/62634391/8428634