# Camunda GET opportunities of XOR Gateway using REST

Tags: angular, rest, bpmn, camunda

I have the following situation:
[image]

What i want to do is to get a dropdown menu in my Angular application where all opportunities of books are listed. So i can choose between 'Harry Potter', 'Moby Dick' and 'Robinson Crusoe'. When i selected one book and press submit i send a POST `/complete` via REST.

It should look like this, whereby the options should always be the same like in the Camunda Model:
[image]

My questions here are: how can i get the information which books i can choose via REST? Is that even possible and is that how it should be done?

Comment: What's Camunda Model?

Comment: The BPMN Diagram

Comment: Something is unclear, where is the data for books to read?

Comment: I want to receive the information from the outgoing arrows from the Exclusive gateway. Im quiet new to Camunda so im not sure if thats even possible

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your question that you want to access gateway route values and convert it into a drop-down menu before even reaching there.
As far as I know it is not possible. Gateways are just the if-else condition to find the execution route.
you can create this drop-down list by passing it to the process execution, keeping it in some script or by taking the data through rest apis.

Answer (score 0):

There is one option that might help you. The idea is to get the BPMN 2.0 XML of a process definition. And you can parse the xml and get the gateways or any element.

The standard result is a an escaped XML string containing the XML that this definition was deployed with.

## Version 7.0 and 7.13

Camunda's API has the following endpoint `/process-definition/{id}/xml`. It returns the `BPMN 2.0` XML of the process defition.

## Version 7.13

Added additional endpoints,

Returns the XML for the latest version of the process definition which belongs to no tenant

GET `/process-definition/key/{key}/xml`

Return the XML for the latest version of the process definition for tenant

GET `/process-definition/key/{key}/tenant-id/{tenant-id}/xml`

## Result

Request

```
http://localhost:5115/engine-rest/process-definition/Process_16yhb92:1:1605d9ef-be29-11ea-a3af-0242ac160003/xml
```

Diagram

[image]

Your XML should look like the following:

```
"bpmn20Xml": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<bpmn:definitions xmlns:bpmn=\"http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL\" xmlns:bpmndi=\"http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI\" xmlns:dc=\"http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:di=\"http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI\" id=\"Definitions_0tnus7x\" targetNamespace=\"http://bpmn.io/schema/bpmn\" exporter=\"Camunda Modeler\" exporterVersion=\"3.5.0\">\n  <bpmn:process id=\"Process_16yhb92\" isExecutable=\"true\">\n    <bpmn:startEvent id=\"StartEvent_1\">\n      <bpmn:outgoing>SequenceFlow_05h0ut0</bpmn:outgoing>\n    </bpmn:startEvent>\n    **<bpmn:exclusiveGateway id=\"ExclusiveGateway_1\">\n**      
...
...
sourceRef=\"Task_1mivaws\" targetRef=\"ExclusiveGateway_1\" />\n
```

Comment: I got you. So there might be a way to read out the information from xml via regex for example... still feels a little bit "hacky".
I tried to define a `Form Field` with type enum where all the possible values `C#, C, Camunda` can be choosen. I dont know if thats a "clean" way on how to do that? With `/task/{id}/form-variables` i can at least find out if the form contains a boolean or enum etc. Via `/task/{id}/rendered-form` i can get the HTML of the form. Currently I try to include the HTML in my code instead of the dropdown like its done in Camunda Tasklist. May I do it like this???

Comment: Sure, It's "hacky", this is just showing you that reading that value is possible. Another thing is if you should pursue that and how you are going maintain the values. What is easier for you? And requires less maintenance. Your requirements and time play a role here.

Comment: But there must be a clean way to do it. In Camunda Tasklist the Form also gets visualized and the value gets forwarded to the gateway. I want to do exactly that with the difference not to choose via Camunda Cockpit but in my Angular application. In best case in a non hacky way ;)

Comment: Then, the camunda sdk can be useful for you > https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-examples/tree/master/sdk-js/browser-forms <

Comment: I didnt get this to run in my Angular 7 Application. What i did now is to parse the xml from  my BPMN to JSON and pull out the information i need. It is hacky but i dont know what else to do...